# How can I fix Youtube videos only displaying black with sound in iOS's Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, youtube

Frequently I encounter this problem in iOS's Safari:  I want to watch a Youtube video, and  it starts playing, but the display area is entirely in black, although I can still hear the audio.   Is there some sort of hack that will get the videos to play normally, with a 100% success rate?  Quite frequently I have to refresh multiple times (>5) to get those videos to start playing.

Answer (score 1):

Forcing Safari to quit works reliably for me. Double click the home button,tap the 'X' on Safari.